# How to solve the Frobenius-norm minimization?

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces

I am looking for a way to determine a matrix $W \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, such that

$$||W^TW-\lambda^2\mathbf{I}||_{\rm F}^2$$

gets minimized, where $\mathbf{I}$ is the $m$-dimensional identity matrix, $||\cdot ||_{\rm F}$ is the Frobenius-norm. In fact, I'm looking for a way in which the matrix $W$ gets as close as possible to the identity matrix. I'd be grateful for all helpful advices or even solutions!

Comment: In the case that $m \leq n$, this is a trivial problem

Comment: What does it mean for a non-square matrix to be close to the identity matrix? I assume $m<n$, also? Is $\lambda$ fixed? Why are you not setting $\lambda=1$ with your goal? At any rate, you can certainly make $W^\top W = \lambda^2 I$ by choosing the columns of $W$ to be $\lambda$ times an orthonormal set of $m$ vectors in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: I assume that $\lambda$ is real. In the case that $m > n$, we can deduce from the [EYM theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation) that this is minimized if and only if we have $W = \lambda V$ for a matrix $V$ satisfying $VV^T = I$. The minimum value attained will be $\lambda^2(m-n)$.

Comment: Rather, the minimum value is $\lambda^4(m-n)$.

Answer (score 0):

The singular value decomposition (SVD) of the real matrix $\mathbf W$ is a factorization of the form $$\mathbf W=\mathbf U\mathbf \Lambda \mathbf V^T$$ where $\mathbf U$ and $\mathbf V$ are unitary matrices and the diagonal of $\mathbf \Lambda\triangleq\operatorname{diag}\left\{w_1,w_2,\cdots,w_m\right\}, w_k\geq 0\forall k$, contains all singular of $\mathbf W$.

Put the above decomposition into the initial problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Vert\mathbf W^T\mathbf W-\lambda^2 \mathbf I\Vert_F^2&=\Vert\mathbf V\mathbf \Lambda^2 \mathbf U^T-\lambda^2 \mathbf I\Vert_F^2\\
&=\Vert\mathbf\Lambda^2-\lambda^2 \mathbf I\Vert_F^2\\
&=\left(w_1^2-\lambda^2\right)^2+\left(w_2^2-\lambda^2\right)^2+\cdots+\left(w_m^2-\lambda^2\right)^2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Then, we need to minimize all subproblems as follows
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\min\limits_{w_k} & \vert w_k^2-\lambda^2\vert
\end{array}
\end{equation}
So, $w_k=\vert\lambda\vert$ if $w_k\neq0$. Furthermore, each singular value of $\mathbf W$ is $\lambda$ or $0$, i.e., $$\mathbf W=\mathbf U\operatorname{diag}\{\underbrace{\lambda,\lambda,\cdots,\lambda}_{\min\{m,n\}\lambda},0,0,\cdots,0\}\mathbf V^T$$for any unitary matrices $\mathbf U$ and $\mathbf V$.